# Select spring boot xml configuration at runtime

Tags: java, spring-boot, xml-configuration

I have to run a legacy spring boot (2.1.8) app

`SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);`

with XML beans config which must be selected at runtime from the `src/main/resources` dir:
`a/config.xml`
or
`b/config.xml`
based on an env variable with the respective value `a` or `b`. Is there a way to load XML config like this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [Spring Profiles](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles); this might get you where you want to be.

Comment: I know about profiles, but I don't know how to point spring boot to the specific folder with .xml files `x/y/config.xml` They are not loaded at the moment